# Merging of ETL files failed

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've just installed VS2017 in my work computer and I have a problem when I try to debug a simple 'Hello World'. When I lauch the compilation in debug mode the following error is shown :

"Merging of ETL files has failed"

I've read some post regarding this issue but I have not found a solution yet. I've enough disk space so that's not the problem.

Can you please help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: You don't provide any information except the error message. The SO questions that contain the same error contain far more information than this. One is about space but the other is about a WMI service that stopped unexpectedly. There may be other similar questions

Comment: if you have Windows 7, don't run other tools that use ETW like ProcessExplorer, ResMon in background